# FileNotFound when opening bitmap in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm getting the following exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /my_images/IMG_20210611_171332_9015407964570520530.jpg 
at android.conten...
```

for this line of code

```
Bitmap bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), fileUri);
```

Unfortunately I don't have the full stack trace because AppCenter, which I use for logging, is truncating the message.

I'm running this code in response to an activity result where we return from the phone's default camera app to this app.

We get this error in a small percentage of cases and not on all tested phones.

Is it possible that, even though the error says FileNotFoundException, that it is caused by a shortage of RAM when reading the picture?

**Addiotional info**
The image file name that is passed to the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent is generated like this:

```
File storageDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,  ".jpg", storageDir);
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "com.mycompany.myapp.saveimageprovider", image);
```

Comment: Unfortunately you did not inform us about fileUri.

Comment: From the error message, you appear to be passing a bare path (`/my_images/IMG_20210611_171332_9015407964570520530.jpg`) to `getBitmap()`, and that is not going to work... particularly since that path does not exist.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added info on how the image uri was generated. The strange thing is that this problem is intermittent and occurs in a few percent of the times that a picture is taken, Some reports seem to indicate that the problem occurs more often when taking a landscape oriented pic.

Comment: That code defines a `photoURI` variable. Your problem is coming from a `fileUri` object. What is the relationship between these two things? "Some reports seem to indicate that the problem occurs more often when taking a landscape oriented pic" -- make sure that you are holding onto your destination file in the saved instance state `Bundle`, as your process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground, and also to deal with configuration changes.

Comment: I'm saving the fileUri in onSaveInstanceState like this: outState.putString(PhotoUriStateKey, fileUri.getPath()). Then I'm restoring it in onCreate like this: String fileString = savedInstanceState.getString(FileUriStateKey); if (fileString != null && !fileString.isEmpty()); fileUri = Uri.parse(fileString);. Is it enough to restore it in onCreate or should I do it somewhere else also if the process was terminated?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because of two reasons:

**Activity recreated**

When the pictures where taken on some (mainly Samsung) phones in landscape mode the app was recreated when returning from the camera and onCreate was run.

**File uri stored wrong**

When my local fields were stored in onSaveInstanceState I was using fileUri.getPath() to store the photo uri that was sent to the camera. Unfortunately getPath() only returned

/my_images/IMG_20210614_205615_6745415510162969966.jpg

of the whole path that should be

content://com.mycompany.myapp.saveimageprovider/my_images/IMG_20210614_205615_6745415510162969966.jpg

After using fileUri.tostring in onSaveInstanceState everything started working.

Comment: so how did you fix it?

Comment: I switched to ToString() instead of getPath() which gave a full absolute path with schema (check the last row of the answer)